# i want to establish Bluetooth connection between python code running in windows 10 and arduino, is there any way?

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino

i want to send some data(like string) via Bluetooth to arduino from python script running on windows 10 , is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

Your question might be a little broad but I will give you a simple example. You can establish serial communication between your Arduino and your PC through a serial port.
I called PC script as Server and the Arduino as a client. You can edit the COM port if needed.

You can find more about [pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) and [Arduino Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/) and create your own protocol based on your application. Also, There are good articles about that like [this](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-python-tutorial).

`server.py`:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM1',9600)
ser.open()
while True:
    new_data = ser.read()
    if new_data:
        # flush serial
        ser.flushInput()
        print("new data:", new_data)
        ser.write(b"ACK\r")
```

`client.ino`:

```
void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    serial.Begin(9600);
    Serial.print('Hello from Arduino\r');
    delay(1);
    // read respond
    if (Serial.ReadString().indexOf("ACK") != -1)
    {
        //valid answer received
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        //flush Serial
        Serial.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        // no valid answer
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
    }

}

void loop()
{
}
```